# Is the intersection of a chain of covers of a set also a cover for that set?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Suppose $X$ be any non-empty set and $\mathcal{C} = \{\mathcal{U}_{\lambda}:\lambda \in \Lambda\}$ be a chain of covers of $X$. So for every $\lambda$, $X \subseteq \cup_{V\in{\mathcal{U}_{\lambda}}}V$ and if $\lambda_1,\lambda_2 \in \Lambda$, then either $\mathcal{U}_{\lambda_1} \subseteq \mathcal{U}_{\lambda_2}$ or $\mathcal{U}_{\lambda_2} \subseteq \mathcal{U}_{\lambda_1}$.

> Is it then true that $\cap_{\lambda \in \Lambda}\mathcal{U}_{\lambda}$ must also be a cover of $X$?

Intuitively I feel that this must indeed be the case, but I cannot prove it rigorously. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not true: for example, let $X=\mathbb{R}$, let $\Lambda=(0,1)$, and let $$\mathcal{U}_{\lambda}=\{\text{open intervals of length}\leq \lambda\}.$$
Then $\mathcal{C}=\{U_\lambda\mid \lambda\in\Lambda\}$ is a chain of covers, but $\bigcap_{\lambda\in\Lambda}U_{\lambda}=\varnothing$.

Comment: Could you please explain how $\mathcal{U}_{\lambda}$ covers $X$?

Comment: I mean the chain

Comment: @SenoreBunuel: Given any real number $x$ and any $\lambda\in (0,1)$, $x$ is contained in an open interval of length $\leq\lambda$. For example,
$$\left(x-\frac{\lambda}{2},x+\frac{\lambda}{2}\right)$$
is an open interval of length $\lambda$ that works fine.